# iSQLPlus not starting on Port 80

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to change the port for iSQLPlus on my Oracle DB server, by making changes in the file `http-web-site.xml`.

When I change the port to 80, in this file, the iSqlPlus doesn't start. I can nether connect over a browser or telnet to it, even from the host machine itself. On the command line, however, it does not give any errors.

I have tried changing it to other ports that is 8080 and 5560, it is running fine with no problems there.

**I am using `Oracle 10.2.0_10`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
netstat -tan|grep ":80 "
```

That should tell you whether there is already a process running on that port. If not, then you don't have permission to access this port. Ports < 1024 are reserved for the `root` user. This means you must run the process as `root`.